# MongoDB/mongoose - How to handle next call when having multiple operations inside mongoose pre remove hook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my pre hook as of now:

```
OrganisationSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {

  Account.update({'organisations._id': this._id}, {$pull: {'organisations._id': this._id}}, {multi: true}, (err) => {

    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }

    Invite.remove({organisation: this._id}, (err) => {

      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      next();
    });
  });
});
```

This obviously won't work since if there are no `Invite` documents then `next` will never be called.

Preferably what I would like is something like:

```
OrganisationSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {

  Account.update({'organisations._id': this._id}, {$pull: {'organisations._id': this._id}}, {multi: true}, next);
  Invite.remove({organisation: this._id}, next);
});
```

But this solution would fire `next` twice, probably causing an app crash.

Is there an elegant way of waiting for multiple operations to finish before calling `next`? One solution I've been thinking about is having a counter of finished operations which I can then check against the total number of operations, but I feel that there must be a better way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example should work since the callback is always called, even if there are no `Invite` documents.

However, one solution would be to use promises, since mongoose supports them:

```
OrganisationSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
  Promise.all([
    Account.update({'organisations._id': this._id}, {$pull: {'organisations._id': this._id}}, {multi: true}).exec(),
    Invite.remove({organisation: this._id}).exec()
  ])
    .then(next)
    .catch(next)
});
```